# Unable to send Email to group of users

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, groups, sharepoint-email, outgoing-email

I have made a small Project Request tool for our team. The way how this tool is supposed to work is when a users submits a request he gets a confirmation email and then within the team internally 3 separate users get the email. Now the problem I am facing is that the users who is submitting the request is getting the confirmation email. But the three internal team members who are in a group are not getting the email.
But then again when i try to submit the request everything seems to working fine as I have full access.
 I know it might be a silly issue but I am unable to find out what permission am I missing. Can anyone suggest something.

I am using share point 2013

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Its because when a user submits the answers, it takes the permission of the user who has submitted and if they have restricted access then it will not work.

Solution:

Go for app step if you are using 2013 Workflow.

You can elevate the permissions for a particular step. This is nothing but for sending the email alone it takes the permission of the owner(Yourself) who has created the workflow.

If you need steps on how to perform this then kindly let me know i can help further.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi! I guess wat you are suggesting will work for me but I am not sure can you please help me with some steps

Comment: Hi! I was actually able to come up with a solution. By adding a parallel block and it seems to be working fine across all the users.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the permissions between the problematic users and yours, and find the differences.

If you are using a SharePoint Designer workflow to send email, you can use the "Send an email" action in an **Impersonation Step** of a SharePoint 2010 platform workflow. Or use the "Send an email" action in an **App Step** of a SharePoint 2013 platform workflow.

Comment: Ok just a quick thing about this tool . Lets say the tool name is xyz and i have three groups. xyz owner,xyz team members,xyz visitors. So the tool is completely working fine for users in xyz owners group and just to be sure that i am not missing any thing i gave full permissions to people in xyz team members. It is not working for them but the moment I copy them in xyz owners group everything works fine.

Comment: Hi! I was actually able to come up with a solution. By adding a parallel block and it seems to be working fine across all the users.